# CS0118: 'MT.Flag.UmbracoTests' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am following the instructions [on this site](http://umbraco.miketaylor.eu/2010/08/29/authenticating-new-members-part-2/) to create a member login. When I add the  profile provider information to the web.config, I get the following error message:

http://www.pastie.org/1309972

Am I setting this up correctly.

Comment: try just `inherits="MT.Flag.UmbracoTests.MemberProfile"`, dropping the rest

Comment: @Nico ~ You should make that an answer.

Comment: I agree so you can get some points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try just `inherits="MT.Flag.UmbracoTests.MemberProfile"`, dropping the rest